# Tokenizing acronyms combined with numbers in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm attempting to improve my full text search queries to handle cases where acronyms are present and being combined with a number (USD123).

Currently I have a thesaurus defined which can expand known acronyms. For instance, USD is expanded out to "Unified School District" and searches work pretty well.

However we're seeing users combining the acronym with numbers (both documents and queries), such as USD123. Since Postgres considers USD123 a single token, we won't get our desired results.

Example query:

```
# select to_tsquery('usd');
to_tsquery            
---------------------------------
'unifi' & 'school' & 'district'
-- Good!

# select to_tsquery('usd123');
to_tsquery 
------------
'usd123'
-- Bad!
```

Is there a way to make Postgres expand USD123 to "Unified School District 123" and/or tokenize the string as two separate tokens?

Comment: You'll need to preprocess the input (regex), or write an extended text search parser (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-parsers.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/test-parser.html) to do what you want.